# Angular 2: Is it possible to use the same parent component with different child components?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I would like to know if is it possible to define a parent component without specifying which child component to use?

Normally i would create a parent component and use the selector of the child component in the html file

parent-component-1.html:

```
//some logic
<child-component-1-selector></child-component-1-selector>
//some logic
```

If i follow this approach i have to define which kind of child component i wanna use. But if i wanna use the parent component multiple times with different child components, i have to copy the logic part and create separate parent-components:

parent-component-1.html:

```
//some logic
<child-component-1-selector></child-component-1-selector>
//some logic
```

parent-component-2.html:

```
//some logic (same as above)
<child-component-2-selector></child-component-2-selector>
//some logic (same as above)
```

I don't like the approach because i would generate code duplicates. Is there a way to define the parent-component without specifying which child component to render and just 'pass' the child component as an argument?

current approach, 
grand-parent-component.html:

```
<parent-component-1></parent-component-1>
<parent-component-2></parent-component-2>
```

suggested approach, 
grand-parent-component.html:

```
<parent-component-selector [childcomponent] = "child-component-1"></parent-component-selector>
<parent-component-selector [childcomponent] = "child-component-2"></parent-component-selector>
```

I hope i have made my self clear about my 'problem'. Maybe you guys can help me and give suggestions about best practices

Comment: `<child-component-1 *ngIf="someCondition"></child-component-1><child-component-2 *ngIf="someOtherCondition"></child-component-2>`? Or maybe you want to use the router?

Comment: what you have suggested also has duplication of codes. content inside the **parent-component-selector** is also duplicated

Comment: @JBNizet that is one solution, but if i have like 10 child-components it doesn't seem that clean to me if i use an if expression

Comment: @Aravind yes, but the parent-component itself only exists once. If i have parent-component-1 and parent-component-2 there exists code duplicates inside this two components

Comment: i would really like to create some kind of modular solution so i can use the parent-component in multiple projects

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to do something like:

```
<my-custom-panel>
   <here-is-one-inner-component>
</my-custom-panel>
```

And then in another place,

```
<my-custom-panel>
   <some-other-component>
</my-custom-panel>
```

If i'm reading you right, then you're basically looking at using Angular's content projection.

So, in my example above, I'd write my-custom-panel component to look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-panel',
  template: `
     <div class="wrapper">
       <h1>My Heading</h1>
       <ng-content></ng-content>
     </div>
  `
})
export class ....
```

The trick is that `<ng-content>` tag, which acts as a marker in the component's template. When using my-custom-panel in another template, any content that appears within the `my-custom-panel` tag will get projected right next to that `<ng-content>` tag.

Hopefully, an example will make things clearer. So, in the case of my first example, where the template using my-custom-panel is:

```
<my-custom-panel>
   <here-is-one-inner-component>
</my-custom-panel>
```

That will get transformed into:

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <h1>My Heading</h1>
       <ng-content></ng-content>
       <here-is-one-inner-component>
</div>
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Sometimes its hard to search without knowing the needed keyword. In my case the keyword seems to be "transclusion" (https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content). Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help.   FYI, Angular 1 (i.e. AngularJS) called it transclusion - Angular (2+) now calls it content projection - different terms for the same concept

Comment: thanks. this is great and exactly what i was looking for.